# Swift 2: Is there any way to use 'default' in the switch statement of enum with associated values?

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, enumeration

I have a recursive enumeration, where most of the cases have same types of associated values:

```
indirect enum Location {
    case Title(String?)
    case Region(Location)
    case Area(Location, Location)
    case City(Location, Location)
    case Settlement(Location, Location)
    case Street(Location, Location)
    case House(Location, Location)
}
```

What I want to do is to form a nice string description, which will include all non-nil titles.

```
func getStringFromLocation(location: Location) -> String? {
    var parts: [String?] = []

    switch location {
    case .Title(let title): return title
    case .House(let title, let parent):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    case .Street(let title, let parent):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    case .Settlement(let title, let parent):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    case .City(let title, let parent):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    case .Area(let title, let parent):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    case .Region(let title):
        parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
    }

    return parts
        .filter { $0 != nil }
        .map { $0! }
        .joinWithSeparator(", ")
}
```

The problem is that five out of seven possible cases are exactly the same and I have a bunch of copy-pasted code which, as I suppose, is not good. What if I had an enumeration of a hundred cases?

Is there any way to write something like this?

```
switch location {
case .Title(let title): 
    parts.append(title)
case .Region(let title):
    parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
default (let title, let parent):
    parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
    parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
}
```

...using some default case to handle all similar cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Paul's concern that it is odd to nest `Location` precisely this way, the basic problem is solvable. Personally, I wouldn't solve it with a `default`, I'd just simplify the code and use the tools Swift gives us (like `CustomStringConvertible`; I also put labels on your data; it was too confusing with just two `Location` elements that had completely different meanings):

```
indirect enum Location: CustomStringConvertible {
    case Title(String?)
    case Region(Location)
    case Area(title: Location, parent: Location)
    case City(title: Location, parent: Location)
    case Settlement(title: Location, parent: Location)
    case Street(title: Location, parent: Location)
    case House(title: Location, parent: Location)

    var description: String {

        func format(locs: (Location, Location)) -> String {
            return [locs.0, locs.1].map{$0.description}.filter{$0 != ""}.joinWithSeparator(", ")
        }

        switch self {
        case .Title(let title): return title ?? ""

        case .Region(let title): return "\(title)"

        case .House(let data):      return format(data)
        case .Street(let data):     return format(data)
        case .Settlement(let data): return format(data)
        case .City(let data):       return format(data)
        case .Area(let data):       return format(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I unload the entire tuple into `data`. You don't have to break the tuple apart in pattern matching. Enumerations never have multiple associated data. They always have exactly one: a tuple. (The same is true of functions. All functions take one value and return one value. That value just might happen to be a tuple.)

But if you really wanted to get rid of that repeated `return format(data)`, then you can through `Mirror`. (You can solve a rather shocking number of things through `Mirror`. You should be very careful before you do. This case is just duplicated typing, not duplicated logic. A little duplicated typing is not something you should create a lot of complexity to remove.)

Here's how you'd do it:

```
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Title(let title): return title ?? ""

    case .Region(let title): return "\(title)"

    default:
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        guard let locs = (m.children.first?.value as? (Location, Location)) else {
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected data in enum. Probably missing a case somewhere.")
        }
        return [locs.0, locs.1].map{$0.description}.filter{$0 != ""}.joinWithSeparator(", ")
    }
}
```

The lesson here is that the first child of an enum is a tuple of all of its data.

But using `Mirror` is much more fragile (notice I opened the possibility of crashing). And while an enum is possibly a great tool here, you still may want to rethink this data structure.

Comment: Thank you, Rob! I've got your point and it looks pretty clear! I wanted to try using these recursive enums, but you and Paul convincing me to do what I have intended to and totally agree with - it's better to use more traditional data structures ). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For modern readers of this old question, you can actually bind the same associated values from several cases nowadays. As long as the types match.

```
case .house(let title, let parent), .street(let title, let parent):
    parts.append(getStringFromLocation(parent))
    parts.append(getStringFromLocation(title))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way for Swift’s pattern matching to match across different enum values that happen to have identical associated values. That is the answer to your immediate question.

It is possible, as Rob wisely suggests, to refactor repeated code out of case statements — but it is not possible for a single case statement to match across enum values *and* extract the associated values.

---

The fact that you’re finding yourself wanting to do this suggests that you may want to reconsider your enum design. There is shared behavior and shared structure between many of the cases, but enum cases are supposed to be mutually exclusive and independent.

Perhaps Area, City, Settlement, Street, and House are all really the same kind of thing?

```
indirect enum Location {
    case Title(String?)
    case Region(Location)
    case BinaryLocation(BinaryKind, Location, Location)

    enum BinaryKind {
        case Area
        case City
        case Settlement
        case Street
        case House
    }
}
```

(I don’t understand what the meaning of those two associated locations is, but since you do, I’d recommend coming up with more explanatory names than `BinaryLocation` and `BinaryKind`.)

This might not even be an appropriate situation for enums at all; for example, something like this might play out better:

```
protocol Location {
    var description: String { get }
}

struct Title: Location {
    var title: String?

    var description: String {
        return title
    }
}

// ... and one for Region, and then ...

protocol BinaryLocation {
    var child0: Location { get }
    var child1: Location { get }
}

extention BinaryLocation: Location {
    var description: String {
        return "\(child0), \(child1)"
    }
}

// ...and then either individual structs for House, Street, etc., or
// an enum like BinaryKind above.
```

I can’t say, because I don’t know the whole of your situation.

What I *can* say is that your concern about the repeated code is valid, and that specific concern is a clue to take a step back and look at the big picture of your model. Taking nit-picky type strictness questions as cues to rethink your modeling choices is the “Swift way:”

1. “Why am I getting this error / hitting this wall?” becomes…
2. “Why does the compiler think that?” becomes…
3. (a) “What assertions am I making in my model about the structure of my problem domain?” (b) “Do those assertions hold up?”

Comment: Actually, I was going to suggest rethinking the use of an enum here in the first place. It seems cool at first blush but it's clear that it's just getting in the way.

Comment: The arbitrary nesting of locations in a binary tree smells funny to me. For example, what would it mean to have `House(Region(Title("midwest")), City(Region(Title("subsaharan Africa")), House(Title("grandma’s house"))))`? I’d start there.